# BSD and Makefile

Tags: makefile, freebsd

Здравствуйте.

Такая проблема. Есть Makefile, который отлично собирается на linux, но отчяанно не хочет делать то же самое на Freebsd.

В чём проблема:

Исходники находятся в поддиректории ./src (туда же хочу пихать объектные файлы). хочу определить переменную CRYPTI_OBJS так, чтобы не приходилось добавлять каждый раз "./src" перед каждым именем файла. Сейчас в Makefile это выполняется за счёт функции patsubst, но на сколько я понимаю это примочка GNU версии.

Как выглядит сейчас мейкфайл.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -ggdb

BIN= ./bin
SRC= ./src
TEST= ./test
INCLUDES= -I ./include
LEX_OBJS = $(patsubst %,src/%, lex.o id_table.o hash.o primes.o keyword.o common.o array.o)
LEX_MAIN = lex_test.o
LEX_TEST = $(BIN)/lex_test

CRYPTI_OBJS = $(patsubst %,src/%,stack.o syntax.o syn_tree.o traverse.o eval.o function.o list.o libcall.o)
CRYPTI_MAIN = crypti.o
CRYPTI_TEST = $(BIN)/crypti

VPATH= ./src

all: $(LEX_TEST) $(CRYPTI_TEST)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $> -o $@

$(LEX_TEST): $(LEX_OBJS) $(LEX_MAIN)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $>

$(CRYPTI_TEST): $(LEX_OBJS) $(CRYPTI_OBJS) $(CRYPTI_MAIN)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $>

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(SRC)/*.o
    rm $(CRYPTI_TEST) $(LEX_TEST)

test: $(CRYPTI_TEST)
    bash $(TEST)/calc_test.sh
    bash $(TEST)/memory_test.sh

rebuild: clean $(CRYPTI_TEST)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста варианты решения моей проблемы (т.е. не GNU методы автоматического добавления поддиректории перед именем файла).

Comment: А что значит "не хочет"? Выдаёт сообщение "I don't want!"?

Comment: @alexlz Значит что не собирается файл, не обрабатываются переменные LEX_OBJS и CRYPTI_OBJS, они показаны как пустые (выводил через echo, прописав его в одном из правил). Связано это с тем (IMHO) что в не гнутой версии нету функций которые я пытаюсь использовать при определении этих переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме как разбить Makefile на два (один в ./ , другой в ./src), т.е. вывернуть сборку наизнанку ничего в голову не лезет.

В ./Makefile оствляете все clean и т.п., а в all:

```
all:
        (cd $(SRC); make)
```

В ./src/Makefile получается что-то вроде

```
BIN    = ../bin
INCLUDES= -I ../include
LEX_OBJS = lex.o id_table.o hash.o primes.o keyword.o common.o array.o
LEX_MAIN = ../lex_test.o
LEX_TEST = $(BIN)/lex_test

CRYPTI_OBJS = stack.o syntax.o syn_tree.o traverse.o eval.o function.o list.o libcall.o # понятно в одну строку (в этом редакторе не получается)
CRYPTI_MAIN = ../crypti.o
CRYPTI_TEST = $(BIN)/crypti

all:   $(LEX_TEST) $(CRYPTI_TEST)
```

дальше правила для сборки, как у Вас. Что-то в таком духе.

А если откровенно, я не люблю так разбрасывать все по разным каталогам. Если надо, то я бы в src делал библиотеку (.a) и линковался с ней из Makefile в ./bin, ./test и т.п. где и лежали бы main-ы. Ну, install, clean, tar ... вызов сборки библиотеки, программ в BIN и тестов сделал бы в "главном" Makefile.

Comment: @gg4me, еще один вариант, это взять исходники GMAKE и собрать их в BSD.

Comment: @avp Спасибо, наверное придётся распределить задачи по вложенным Makefile.